# After Angular upgrade and adding Module Federation Plugin browser is not loading application

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular12, webpack-module-federation

We have added Angular Module Federation Plugin. After added build is successful but when we run ng serve and try to view application in browser getting below error

NPM version : 6.14.13

Angular CLI: 12.1.4

Node: 14.17.1

Package Manager: yarn 1.22.10

OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.1.4

typescript: 4.3.5

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(e)[t -> t -> Qe -> e -> e -> e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
        at pu.get (716.js:1)
        at Cu.get (716.js:1)
        at Cu.get (716.js:1)
        at Cu.get (716.js:1)
        at dr (716.js:1)
        at Module.hr (716.js:1)
        at Object.e.ɵfac [as factory] (388.js:1)
        at Cu.hydrate (716.js:1)
        at Cu.get (716.js:1)
        at dr (716.js:1)
```

Application Package.json file

```
{
    "name": "nurseline-ui",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng lint && ng serve",
        "build": "ng lint && ng build",
        "build-prod": "ng lint && ng build --prod --base-href /nurseline/",
        "build-prod-all": "npm run clean -all && yarn install && npm run build-prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "lintfix": "ng lint --fix=true",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "clean": "rm -rf node_modules/@anthem",
        "clean-all": "rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf ../nurseline-client/node_modules && rm package-lock.json && rm ../nurseline-client/package-lock.json && rm -rf ../benefits-search/node_modules && rm ../benefits-search/package-lock.json || true",
        "refresh": "npm run clean && npm install && npm run build",
        "refresh-all": "npm run clean-all && npm install && npm run build",
        "format:fix": "pretty-quick --staged",
        "format:fixall": "pretty-quick",
        "precommit": "run-s format:fix lint",
        "format:check": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc --list-different \"src/{app,environments,assets}/**/*{.ts,.js,.json,.css,.scss}\"",
        "run:all": "node node_modules/@angular-architects/module-federation/src/server/mf-dev-server.js"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^12.2.1",
        "@angular/animations": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
        "@angular/forms": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/localize": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/material": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "^12.1.2",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.1.3",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
        "@stomp/ng2-stompjs": "^7.2.0",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "ag-grid-angular": "^25.3.0",
        "ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0",
        "ag-grid-enterprise": "^25.3.0",
        "angular-progress-bar": "^1.0.11",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
        "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "3.6.5",
        "if-env": "1.0.4",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "moment": "^2.27.0",
        "ngx-build-plus": "^12.0.1",
        "ngx-json-viewer": "2.4.0",
        "ngx-markdown": "11.1.3",
        "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.9.1",
        "ngx-toast-notifications": "^1.3.0",
        "ngx-webstorage-service": "4.1.0",
        "rxjs": "6.6.0",
        "vanilla-text-mask": "^5.1.1",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.2",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.1",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.2",
        "eslint": "^7.26.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
        "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
        "husky": "^7.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "lint-staged": "^11.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
    path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
    [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
    output: {
        uniqueName: "mfePOC",
        //publicPath: "auto"
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            
                remotes: {
                    host: {
                        external: "http://localhost:4000/remoteEntry.js" 
                    }
                },
                shared:{
                    "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
                    "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
                    "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: 'auto' }, 
                    "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
                        "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": {singleton: true, strictVersion: true},
                        "subsink": { singleton: true, strictVersion: false },
                    ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
                }
                
        }),
        sharedMappings.getPlugin()
    ],
};
```

Any help is appreciated.